# Formula for Pokemon Go IV's?

Tags: pokemon-go

How are pokemon's individual values calculated? Simple question, I'm trying to make an app for personal use.

Answer (score 0):

> HP = (Base Stamina + Stamina IV) * Level(CPScalar)
>
> CP = (Base Atactk + Attack IV) * (Base Deffense + Deffense IV)^0.5 * (Base Stamina + Stamina IV)^0.5 * Level(CPScalar)^2 / 10

I found this formula off of multiple IV calculator sites. However using a site like [Poké Assistant](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator) is easier than making an app and more reliable. This formula isn't perfect, and if you don't know what some of these mean they can be found online as well. (If you need a simpler formula, or don't know how to find these values, again it can be easier to use a website).